# Credentials 'omit' and SET-COOKIE header

Tags: http, cookies, react-apollo

Is it possible to configure an apollo client to not send the cookies in every request (for example with credentials set to `omit`) and still accept cookies from the server that are on the SET-COOKIE header ?

My `httpLink` implementation looks like this:

```
const httpLink = createHttpLink({
  uri,
  fetch: fetch,
  credentials: 'omit'
});
```

However the omit prevents the response from updating the cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Are you by chance using the `ApolloBoostClient`? I experienced the same issue you're having and after [stumbling upon this issue](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/3265#issuecomment-441477460) was able to work around it by instead using the `ApolloClient` as suggested***:

```
export const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: createHttpLink({
    credentials: 'include',
    uri: 'http://localhost:8080/api/graphql',
  }),
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});`
```

*** Except like you I used `'omit'` instead of `'include'` and I'm using ScalaJS and not native JS